# How to set speedProfile when using the HERE Fleet Telematics API?

Tags: here-api

I need to use the Fleet Telematics API since I need to calculate tolls (since the routing API doesn't), and I want to adjust the `speedProfile` to fast.

I see I can do that with the `speedProfile` [parameter for the routing api](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-speed-profile-type.html), but that parameter seems to do nothing for the fleet telematics API.

So, is there no way to set the speed profile for the fleet telematics api? I need to use truck routing, but want normal car speed.

Or, is there another API that will calculate tolls AND let me adjust the speed profile?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is no speedProfile parameter for the fleet telematics API. But, it is possible to use speedFcCat parameter to override the default driven speed values.

From the documentation [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html)
speedFcCat: Comma separated list of speeds driven in kilometer per hour per road functional class (1-5 + Virtual Connections VC) and speed category (1-8) (f.e. FC1-SC1,FC1-SC2,...,FC1-SC8;FC2-SC1,FC2-SC2,...;...;VC-SC1,FC-SC2,...VC-SC8). Functional classes are semicolon separated. Can contain empty entries (no change to default f.e. 80,76,,,,,,;,,,54,46,,,;...).